# Syncing Chrome Extension Settings w/ Dropbox

Tags: google-chrome, backup, sync, dropbox

I was wondering where I could find the settings for extensions in Google Chrome so I can create a symbolic link to synchronize the information w/ Dropbox until Google offers an official solution.  It'd give me great peace of mind as a Greasemonkey developer!

I'm on Mac OS 10.6.7 Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are stored in the Local Storage area of the User Data folder. The exact path depends on the OS you are using:

#### macOS

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

#### Windows XP

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\
```

#### Windows Vista / 7 / 10

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\
```

#### Linux

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

---

[image: info] **Note:** the files (SQLite) are each named:

```
chrome-extension_<an alpha code of some sort>_0.localstorage
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/272192/483176) is outdated, nowadays the settings for extensions are stored in [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) storages in the following directories:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<PROFILE>\Local Extension Settings`
- macOS: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/<PROFILE>/Local Extension Settings`
- Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/<PROFILE>/Local Extension Settings`

`<PROFILE>` should be `Default` if there is only one user in the browser.

Additionally, for extensions that support syncing settings, the settings are stored in the `Sync Extension Settings` directory as well.